# How to simplify this expression?

Tags: calculus

The question just asks me to simplify this expression:

$$\frac{3 - \sqrt{x}}{x - 9}.$$

I'm stuck. I tried rationalizing, but I'm not sure if that's the correct method. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what is within the square root and what is the denominator?

Comment: \frac{3 - \sqrt{x}}{x - 9}

Comment: Its just (3-√x)/(x-9)
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean by simplifying that expression?

$\frac{3-\sqrt{x}}{x-9}=\frac{3-\sqrt{x}}{x-9}\frac{3+\sqrt{x}}{3+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{9-x}{x-9}\frac{1}{3+\sqrt{x}}=\frac{-1}{3+\sqrt{x}}$

Usually we apply this process in reverse to rationalize.

Comment: Oh yeah, I messed up my signs, thank you very much

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: So if  we have to let g(x) be the result from the simplification. Is domain of f equal to domain of g?

Comment: The domains will not quite be the same. $f(x)=\frac{3-\sqrt{x}}{x-9}$ is technically defined (by this formula) on the positive reals excluding $9$ since there is a singularity there. $g(x)=\frac{-1}{3+\sqrt{x}}$ is defined on the positive reals. The above simplification shows we can enlarge the domain of $f$ to the positive reals by defining $f(9)=\frac{-1}{6}$.